# Run script to ssh

Tags: scripts

I use a script to run a subscript. 
The subscript actually ssh's to WDcloud. 
After running subscript, I need to run certain commands in the ssh session of WDcloud. 
But after running the subscript which connects to ssh, the following lines are not running within the ssh session.

The script is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh2cloud.sh
commands_to_run_in_ssh
```

Comment: I think we would need to see what ssh2cloud.sh is doing.

Comment: Kinda ssh root@192.268.2.1

Comment: Then add $* at the end of ssh line so parameters are passed to ssh. "ssh root@192.268.2.1 $*" (http://osr507doc.xinuos.com/en/OSUserG/_Passing_to_shell_script.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh Server <<Limiter
Commands
You
Need
To
Run
Limiter
```

This should solve your problem. If you want to know more look at [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)